# How to extract type list from tuple for struct/class

Tags: c++, templates, variadic-templates, c++20, template-argument-deduction

I want to use a static method in a class that gets a type list in the form `std::tuple<T1, T2, T3,...>`. Instead of working with `std::tuple<...>` I want to have `<...>`.
How to implement example `struct x` resulting in `Ts == <T1, T2, T3,...>`

```
template<template <typename...> typename TL, typename... Ts>
struct x {
    static void test() {
        // expecting Ts == <int, char, float, double> (without std::tuple<>)
        std::cout << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << '\n';
    }
};
```

```
using types = std::tuple<int, char, float, double>;
x<types>::test();
```

See [example on godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/rc9Gvhsn8)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It seems to me that you're looking for template specialization.

Something as

```
// declaration (not definition) for a template struct x
// receiving a single template parameter 
template <typename>
struct x;

// definition for a x specialization when the template
// parameter is in the form TL<Ts...>
template<template<typename...> typename TL, typename... Ts>
struct x<TL<Ts...>> {
    static constexpr void test() {
        // you can use Ts... (and also TL, if you want) here
        std::cout << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << ' ' << sizeof...(Ts) << '\n';            
    }
};
```